# Safe way create strings for evaling in bash

Tags: bash, perl

Want prepare a string in `perl` for evaling it in `bash` like:

```
str="$( perl -E '$sq=chr(047);say qq{var1=${sq}hello world${sq}}' )" #this just for demo - the real perl scirpt is ofcourse real complex script ...
echo "got for eval: [[$str]]"
eval "$str"
echo "var1        : [[$var1]]"
```

it prints:

```
got for eval: [[var1='hello world']]
var1        : [[hello world]]
```

or course the `eval` is dangerous, so the perl script need to do some preparations.

One thing is, replace all `'` (single quotes) in the value with `'"'"'`, so the when assigning `don't do this` into `var` it should be printed as

```
var='don'"'"'t do this' #safe for eval.
```

Are here some more considartions what i should follow in the perl script for preparing the variable assingnment (`var='some content'`) strings for **safe** `eval`?

fragments from my real script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub make_var {
    my($name, $value) = @_;
    die "Wrong variable name [$name]" if $name =~ /\W/;
    my $sval = sanitise($value);
    #warn qq{$name='$sval'\n};
    print qq{$name='$sval'\n};
}

sub sanitise {
    my $str = shift;
    $str =~ s/'/'"'"'/gs;
    # what more i should do here?
    return $str;
}

#usage
make_var('var1', q{some
multiline
value
where i should'nt miss
escape the single quotes});
```

prints a string safe for eval.

```
var1='some
multiline
value
where i should'"'"'nt miss
escape the single quotes'
```

**EDIT**: Rationale behind this:

In the `bash`  i need many variables, for which the values are generated by the `perl` script. For one variable, i could do:

```
var="$(my_script)"
```

but i need in the bash script many variables. Doing

```
var1="$(my_script some args)"
var2="$(my_script other args)"
...
var10="$(my_script bla bla)"
```

is fairly expensive and slow. (The perl script does many things, the most expensive is - it fetches json from the web...) Therefore, want reduce the number of callings into one - such need the `eval`.

Somme werid pattern comes into my mind:

```
';date;':      var2=''"'"';date;'"'"':' # the escaping solves it
$(date)        var='$(date)'            # safe
```

Comment: Why would you like to eval things in bash?

Comment: You should probably write a single Perl script, rather than constantly computing values to return to a `bash` script.

Comment: @chepner - heh, true. Unfortunately, the bash script isn't my responsibiliy. So, can't revrite it fully into perl.

Comment: @kobame: But you're proposing to add an `eval` to the bash code, so why can't it just run a Perl program and exit?

Comment: generate a bash script from perl in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a horrible proposal. I suggest that you forget about eval and instead
write your Perl code so that it returns the values to stdout in a space-separated string. Then you can split it up using `read` in bash

```
read -r var1 var2 var3 rest <<< $(perl -E '...print "val1 val2 val3\n"')
```

If you prefer you could read into an array instead

```
read -r -a vars <<< $(perl -E '...print "val1 val2 val3\n"')
```

Now the values are in `vars[0]`, `vars[1]` and `vars[2]`

If the values may contain whitespace then you should use a different delimiter ( like comma `,` or colon `:` ) that isn't ever used in the data and set `IFS` to that character before the read

Comment: EXCELLENT!  I created a solution based on your idea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Borodin! Based on your idea i created this solution:

The perl script prints a serie of `null terminated` lines in a form:

```
<varname><any variable content>
```

so i have exactly defined and regex parseable structure for every line.

And using the `bash`'s feature *printing into variable* i don't need run the `read` commands in specified order.

The bash script:

```
fetch_external_data() {
    perl p4.pl
}

read_data() {
    regex='^<([a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)><(.*)>$'
    while IFS= read -d '' -r line
    do
        if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]]
        then
            printf -v "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        else
            echo "Ignoring strange line: $line" >&2
        fi
    done < <(fetch_external_data)
}

read_data
echo "var1: [[$var1]]";echo
echo "var2: [[$var2]]";echo
echo "var3: [[$var3]]";echo
```

and the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

our $opt_d;
getopts('d');

sub make_var {
    my($name, $value) = @_;
    die "Wrong variable name [$name]" if $name =~ /\W/;
    return "<$name><$value>" . ($opt_d ? "\n" : "\0");
}

my $all = make_var('var1','hello');
$all .= make_var('var2', q{some
multiline
value '" bla
here $(date) "'});
$all .= make_var('var3', 'world');

binmode(STDOUT);
print $all;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldo?String::ShellQuote)'s `shell_quote` to convert arbitrary text into shell literals.

```
eval "$(
   perl -e'
      use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
      my $str = qq{Some dangerous symbols: \\\x27"!};
      my $cmd = "var1=" . shell_quote($str);
      print($cmd);
  '
)"
printf "%s\n" "$var1"
```

Output:

```
Some dangerous symbols: \'"!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
sub shellquote1
{
    return $_
        unless m([^@%\w:,./=+-]);
    s/\'/\'\\\'\'/g;
    return "'$_'";
}

sub shellquote
{
    return join " ", map { shellquote1 } @_;
}

print shellquote(@ARGV);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl calls Taint. Untainting in perl means applying *any* regex. Perl goes further than bash--Chicken Little crying Sky Is Falling--by asserting that we have specific opportunities and responsibilities to assert our own best "Laziness(Larry Wall)".

bash "untaint" by regex:

```
jump="`cd / ; rm -rf * .*`"
untaint=${jump//*[^-_a-zA-Z0-9]*/}

[ -n "$untaint" ] && eval portal=\${$untaint:=$@}
```

Goal: imagine how we might "prevent arithmetic" by applying regex.